# Check for specific Item in list without Iteration or find()

Tags: python, python-3.x, steam-web-api

So I have a list of SteamApp objects:

```
   >>> games
   [<SteamApp "Counter-Strike: Global Offensive" (730)>, <SteamApp "XCOM: Enemy Unknown" (200510)>]
```

I also have this piece of code:

```
ownscs = []

if '"Counter-Strike: Global Offensive"' in games:
            print('Owns CS')
            ownscs.append(foo)
```

All i want to do is check if someone owns Counter-Strike
but here comes the crux of the matter, the list games is not iterable and has no attribute find, in case i try those two i get:

```
if any('"Counter-strike: Global Offensive"' in s for s in games):
TypeError: argument of type 'SteamApp' is not iterable
```

and

```
if games.find('"Counter-strike: Global Offensive"') != -1:
AttributeError: 'SteamApp' object has no attribute 'find'
```

So my question is: how do i check the list games for Counter-strike: Global Offensive when it's clearly neither iterable nor findable.

I use https://github.com/smiley/steamapi which creates the SteamApp objects if you are wondering what that is.

Comment: You need to know the attributes of the steamapp object. Try `dir(steamapp)`

Comment: A Python `list` is _always_ iterable, so that's not your problem.  That said, your `games = [...]` line doesn't actually create a list.  Were you trying to tell us that the list had already been initialized to contain two `SteamApp` objects?

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase yes that was what i meant to say, not even two but more! the list contains a SteamApp object for every Game.
El'endia's answer with mapping did the trick!

Comment: You said **without iteration** in the title, but iterating over the list is fine- the problem was that you were also trying to treat the `SteamApp` objects as iterable with the `in s`.

Comment: @Galax Yup, i didn't fully understand what i was having in front of me tbh. i thought i could iterate through the object when it was having no iterator.
Sorry for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to find a `str` (string) in a list of `SteamApp` objects. These `SteamApp` objects actually have a method defined for use with `str()`, so this code should work:

```
if "Counter-Strike: Global Offensive" in map(str,games):
            print('Owns CS')
            ownscs.append(foo)
```

Note that I took out the single quotes (I think they're unnecessary) and changed `games` to `map(str,games)`. `map` applies `str` to every item in `games`, which will produce your game list with only the games' names. Do `list(map(str,games))` to see what that list looks like.

Comment: Oh my god, thanks alot, this did the trick, also when looking at `list(map(str,games))` i finally understood how Mapping works, big thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Even though the other answer was already accepted, this alternative is a little more Pythonic, and is closer to the poster's attempt:

```
if 'Counter-strike: Global Offensive' in (s.name for s in games):
```

Note that `s.name` has the same result with this class as `str(s)`, but I feel that using the `name` property adds clarity.